# When I sort my NSTableView by one of the columns then scroll, the cells that I scroll to don't display properly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tableview, nstableview, nsscrollview

I have an `NSTableView` inside and `NSScrollView` in a pretty standard configuration. When I sort the table view (by clicking one of the column headers), everything that is currently visible gets displayed correctly, but when I scroll in any direction (left, right, up, down) the cells that I scroll to haven't been updated correctly. If half a cell was visible when I sorted, it will even display half the cell with the old value and half the cell with the new value when I scroll to view the whole cell.

Whats going on? Can I force the table view to redraw everything when I sort the table?

Answer (score 0):

When you need to redraw table just call:

```
[yourTableViewOutlet reloadData];
```

[Reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

> **reloadData**
>
> Marks the table view as needing redisplay, so it will reload the data
>   for visible cells and draw the new values.

Comment: How do I know when I need to redraw the table though? Is there a callback for when the table is sorted? Or maybe when its scrolled? (although I can imagine that being a big performance hit, redrawing with every scroll)

Comment: @Drew take a look at this apple's example. It should help you http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/NSTableViewBinding/Introduction/Intro.html. And one more question: maybe you are using Core Animation Layers? This can cause this problem.

Comment: When you click the header, in the last line just before `}` call `[_tableView reloadData];`